# Setting socket options on OSX

Tags: macos, sockets, haskell

I'm trying to set the receive timeout on a socket constructed with the `Network.Socket` module. Here's a code snippet:

```
import Network.Socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = PortNumber 3000

main = do
  addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just host) (Just port)
  let serveraddr = head addrinfos
  sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol
  setSocketOption sock RecvTimeOut 120000000
  connect sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
  msg <- recv sock 1024
  putStrLn msg
  sClose sock
```

The `setSocketOption` line throws an exception:

```
*** Exception: setSocketOption: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
```

`setSocketOption` only accepts `Int` arguments for settings, but not all of the socket options want an `Int`. Specifically `RecvTimeOut` and `SendTimeOut` expect a `struct timeval`. Is there another way to set these options from haskell?

I'm running GHC 7.4.2 on OSX 10.8.1

**EDIT:**

`Network.Socket.Options` seems like the best solution here, and getting it to compile on OSX turned out to require only a tiny pull request. As of version 0.2.0.1, [network-socket-options](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-socket-options-0.2.0.1) now compiles on OSX.

**EDIT 2:**
No luck with `Network.Socket.Options`. The `setRecvTimeout` function doesn't seem to have any effect on OSX. I ended up using `timeout` from the `System.Timeout` package as a workaround.

```
msg <- timeout 120000000 $ recv sock 1024
```

Comment: Does this help: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-October/016586.html?  Or this: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network-socket-options/0.2/doc/html/Network-Socket-Options.html?

Comment: On Mac OS X and Linux, GHC uses non-blocking socket I/O, which is not affected by socket timeouts.  Using `System.Timeout` is the correct way to time out I/O operations.  Unfortunately, [network I/O currently can't be interrupted on Windows](https://github.com/haskell/network/issues/75), so you'll have to use socket timeouts as a workaround.  For portability, use both socket timeouts *and* `System.Timeout`.

Answer (score 2):

I read about Haskell and struct definitions from here: http://therning.org/magnus/archives/315
. The struct timeval definition from the MSDN here (Its the same struct on GNU and probably on OSX): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560(v=vs.85).aspx

the time C-header:

```
...
typedef struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;
    long tv_usec;
} timeval;
....
```

It seems like you need to define some kind of struct constructor in Haskell. Or a complete binding to the time headers like that(taken from http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bindings-common/0.1.4/doc/html/src/CTypes.html ) :

```
                module CTypes where
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

-- time.h

data Tm = Tm {
    tm'sec,
    tm'min,
    tm'hour,
    tm'mday,
    tm'mon,
    tm'year,
    tm'wday,
    tm'yday,
    tm'isdst :: CInt
   }

instance Storable Tm where
    sizeOf _ = fromIntegral size_of_tm
    alignment = sizeOf
    peek p =
        with 0 $ \p1 -> with 0 $ \p2 -> with 0 $ \p3 ->
        with 0 $ \p4 -> with 0 $ \p5 -> with 0 $ \p6 ->
        with 0 $ \p7 -> with 0 $ \p8 -> with 0 $ \p9 ->
        c2hs_tm p p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 >>
        peek p1 >>= \v1 -> peek p2 >>= \v2 -> peek p3 >>= \v3 ->
        peek p4 >>= \v4 -> peek p5 >>= \v5 -> peek p6 >>= \v6 ->
        peek p7 >>= \v7 -> peek p8 >>= \v8 -> peek p9 >>= \v9 ->
        return $ Tm v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9
    poke p (Tm v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9) =
        hs2c_tm p v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9

foreign import ccall size_of_tm :: CInt

foreign import ccall hs2c_tm
    :: Ptr Tm -> CInt -> CInt -> CInt -> CInt ->
       CInt -> CInt -> CInt -> CInt -> CInt -> IO ()

foreign import ccall c2hs_tm
    :: Ptr Tm -> Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt ->
       Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt -> Ptr CInt ->
       Ptr CInt -> IO ()

-- sys/time.h

data Timeval = Timeval {timeval'tv_sec, timeval'tv_usec :: CLong}

instance Storable Timeval where

    sizeOf _ = fromIntegral size_of_timeval

    alignment = sizeOf

    peek p =
        with 0 $ \p1 ->
        with 0 $ \p2 ->

        c2hs_timeval p p1 p2 >>

        peek p1 >>= \v1 ->
        peek p2 >>= \v2 ->

        return $ Timeval {timeval'tv_sec = v1, timeval'tv_usec = v2}

    poke p v = hs2c_timeval p (timeval'tv_sec v) (timeval'tv_usec v)

foreign import ccall "size_of_timeval" size_of_timeval
    :: CInt

foreign import ccall "hs2c_timeval" hs2c_timeval
    :: Ptr Timeval -> CLong -> CLong -> IO ()

foreign import ccall "c2hs_timeval" c2hs_timeval
    :: Ptr Timeval -> Ptr CLong -> Ptr CLong -> IO ()
```

A stripped down to the necessary version would be:

```
module CTypes where
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

-- sys/time.h

data Timeval = Timeval {timeval'tv_sec, timeval'tv_usec :: CLong}
```

You should then be able to initialize a timeval struct by:

```
timeval <- Timeval { tv_sec=120 , tv_usec=0 }
```

I hope that helps a bit...